# can't retrieve error through getsockopt while errno = 13

Tags: c, udp, errno, getsockopt

The following code opens a UDP socket and binds to a privileged port which fails. I want to retrieve the error through getsockopt (SO_ERROR) but I can't. The errno var is 13 but from getsockopt I get 0. I was under the impression getsockopt was the preferred method?

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    int _fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,
                       IPPROTO_UDP);

    int on = 1;
    int rc = setsockopt (_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                               reinterpret_cast<char *> (&on), sizeof (on));
    assert(rc == 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; // Use IPv4
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(151); // Bind port
    
    rc = rc | bind (_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

    int err = -1;
    socklen_t len = sizeof err;
    int rc2 = getsockopt (_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &err, &len);
    printf("end rc=%i rc2=%i err=%i errno=%i : %m\n", rc, rc2, err, errno);
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: I think SO_ERROR is for network/protocol errors, not local errors like permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what `SO_ERROR` is for.  It's not a substitute for `errno` - that has already told you why the call to `bind` failed.

Instead, it is meant to be used for established connections that might encounter an error condition which cannot be reported immediately (such as an asychronous operation on a non-blocking socket).  There's a better description than the rather bare-bones man page here:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zvse/6.2?topic=SSB27H_6.2.0/fa2ti_call_getsockopt.htm